# Cannot Run .NET 5 Windows Form on Raspberry Pi - Framework not Found

Tags: c#, .net-core, raspberry-pi

I've been trying to create an app with a Windows Form GUI that can run on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+. As of right now, it's a dirt-simple form with two buttons (ON & OFF) and the necessary `_Click` function (in C#), using `System.Device.Gpio` to write to one particular pin that I have a breadboard hooked up to.

My issue is that I can't run it successfully on the Raspberry. I tried following the guide at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/iot/deployment.

I published it in *Framework-dependent* deployment mode and with a target runtime of *Portable*. Then, I transferred it to the Raspberry Pi.

When I tried to run `dotnet <<FILENAME>>.dll` on the Pi, it responded that:

```
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App', version '5.0.0' was not found.
- No frameworks were found.
```

The Pi has a .NET version of 5.0.401 installed. Maybe there's no way to run a Windows Form app on a Raspberry, although I saw one video that seemed to get it working (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZBsLR6QotoQ). Trying to run the executable with Mono didn't work either. It replied that `Cannot open assembly '<<FILENAME>>': File does not contain a valid CIL image.`

Comment: _Windows_ Forms is not supported on the Raspberry Pi because it doesn't run a _Windows_ operating system. The video you linked is targeting .NET Framework and uses Mono to run the application on Raspberry Pi (you're using .NET Core, which is completely different and not supported by Mono).

Comment: Thanks. That's what I figured. (sigh)

Comment: As far as I can tell `System.Device.Gpio` is built for .NET Standard 2.0, which means it's supported by .NET Framework 4.6.1 and higher. Thus if you don't have anything else restricting you to .NET 5, you should be able to target .NET Framework 4.7.2 or 4.8 instead and run that (and WinForms) with Mono.

Comment: @VisualVincent The current version of `System.Device.Gpio` is built for NetStandard2.0, NetCoreApp 2.1 and Net 5.0. Net 5.0 is the preferred runtime, especially on the Pi.